# Are Polish space and LCCB space related?

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, descriptive-set-theory

It seems these spaces are the most useful ones for doing probabilities. Are LCCB (locally compact with countable basis) somewhat more general spaces that when endowed with a metric become Polish? I think I once knew the answer to this question. Thanks

Comment: What is a LCCB?

Comment: Probably Locally Compact with a Countable Base

Comment: yes, sorry just added it.

Comment: Did you mean to ask if a locally compact second-countable metrizable space is neccessarily Polish?

Comment: By locally compact with countable basis, do you mean sigma-locally-compact ? if yes, the space would have lindelöf property, and if it is endowed with a metric, it would be separable.

Answer (score 6):

**Theorem.** Every locally-compact second-countable Hausdorff space is a Polish space.

I thought I'd quote a sketch of proof of above fact from somewhere else.

The following sketch is from https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2008/08/polish_spaces.html

> if X is second countable locally compact Hausdorff, then the one-point
>   compactification X+ is metrizable and compact, hence complete (under
>   any metric), and of course second countable, hence X+ is Polish. An
>   open subspace of a Polish space is Polish, hence X is Polish.
>
> Bourbaki (which I found as a Google Book result) provided invaluable
>   assistance.

As for why an open subspace of a Polish space is Polish, again from the same link:

> I had no idea that an open set of a Polish space was Polish — it
>   seemed pretty tough removing that extra point and finding a complete
>   metric on what’s left.
>
> I now see how easy this is: we start with a metric on the one-point
>   compactification X+, remove the point at infinity, and ‘stretch’ the
>   metric near the removed point to get a complete metric on X.

As for why the one-point compactification is metrizable, the selected answer from the following thread explains how to build a local countable basis at infinity:

[If $X$ is locally compact, second countable and Hausdorff, then $X^*$ is metrizable and hence $X$ is metrizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988557/if-x-is-locally-compact-second-countable-and-hausdorff-then-x-is-metriza)

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of research I found that A locally compact space that is Hausdorff (LCH) will be sigma-locally-compact. 
Also that a LCCB will be metrizable (with a complete metric) and separable thus Polish too. thanks

Comment: The converse doesn't hold, though. Take, for example, $L^1(\mathbb R)$, the set of absolutely integrable Lebesgue-measurable functions on $\mathbb R$ (with any two functions equal almost everywhere being identified). It is a separable Banach space, so it is Polish (and second countable). However, it is _not_ locally compact, because no infinite-dimensional normed vector space is.

Comment: This is true if the space is Hausdorff. There are also LCCB spaces which are not Hausdorff, and hence not metrizable. But the "nice enough" ones are still quasi-Polish, which is a natural generalization of the Polish property for non-Hausdorff spaces.

Answer (score 0):

To extend Jisang Yoo's answer, every *sober* LCCB space is *quasi*-Polish. [Sober](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sober_space) and quasi-Polish are natural generalizations of Hausdorff and Polish, and this result was noted in [the paper which introduced quasi-Polish spaces](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.1445) (section 8).

In fact, being sober is not much of a restriction. If we define spaces in terms of the relationships between open (or closed) sets, rather than focusing on points, then every LCCB space is, essentially, sober.