# Showing that $X$ is locally compact

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Now I would like to change question in [If $X$ is locally compact, second countable and Hausdorff, then $X^*$ is metrizable and hence $X$ is metrizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988557/if-x-is-locally-compact-second-countable-and-hausdorff-then-x-is-metriza).

Is it true that

If $X$ is Hausdorff, second countable, and metrizable, then $X$ is locally compact.

To show that $X$ is locally compact, need to show that for every $x\in X$ has compact neighbourhood, i.e. we can find a nbhd $U_x$ where every sequence has a convergent subsequence. I raise this question because my hunch at [Locally compact Hausdorff space is metrizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1737545/locally-compact-hausdorff-space-is-metrizable) is not true.

Comment: This is not true. Take $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$. It is separable and metrizable, and hence Hausdorff and secound countable, but it can't be locally compact, since it is a infinite dimensional topological vector space.

Answer (score 2):

The irrationals are certainly metrizable (implying Hausdorff also), second countable, but not locally compact.  In fact, they are nowhere locally compact.